# Can i find the code for Java's built in functions?

Tags: java

Can i find the code for Java's built in functions? Such like compareTo, I'm working on a program that store strings it read in as "Terms" in a separate class called Term.

Because of that compareTo function won't work, so I'm planning to writing a compareTo method in the Term class. I'm just wondering if I can find the code for compareTo function and modify it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need the code of the Java standard library to implement a custom `Comparable` class.

Comment: Or you could (as intended) implement the Comparable<T> interface and thus compareTo()

Answer (score 3):

> I'm just wondering if I can find the code for compareTo function and modify it.

This doesn't make sense to me as Comparable is an interface and as such, there **is** no code for the interface's compareTo method, just a method signature which you can easily find in the Java API. Now some classes such as String and all the number wrapper classes, **do** implement the interface and you can search online for the Java source code and check their methods, but they likely will have no bearing on yours, and so this isn't necessary, and is likely little more than a wild goose chase.

Why not simply create your own class that implements `Comparable<T>` write your compareTo to method as needed, one that returns 1 if the current object is "greater than", 0 if equal and -1 if "less than"?

```
public class Term implements Comparable<Term> {

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Term otherTerm) {
       // code in here to return the appropriate int
   }
}
```